# Set Multi-User Field in Sharepoint using Powershell and TaskManager

Tags: powershell, sharepoint-2013

Im using the following to set/update a multi user field in Sharepoint using Powershell:

```
[Microsoft.SharePoint.SPFieldUserValueCollection]$lotsofpeople = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.SPFieldUserValueCollection            
$user1 = $w.EnsureUser("domain\user1");            
$user1Value = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.SPFieldUserValue($w, $user1.Id, $user1.LoginName)            
$user2 = $w.EnsureUser("domain\user2");            
$user2Value = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.SPFieldUserValue($w, $user2.Id, $user2.LoginName);            
$lotsofpeople.Add($user1Value);            
$lotsofpeople.Add($user2Value);            
$i["lotsofpeoplefield"] = $lotsofpeople;            
$i.SystemUpdate($false);
```

This works great in the PS Editor but as soon as I set this up as a repeating task in Win TaskManager, it fails for all items, where SPFieldUserValueCollection contains more than 1 user. Error: "Invalid look-up value.  A look-up field contains invalid data. Please check the value and try again."

Any ideas?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Had the same problem today and it took me some time to solve it.

An explicitly cast solved the problem for me:

```
$i["lotsofpeoplefield"] = [Microsoft.SharePoint.SPFieldUserValueCollection] $lotsofpeople
$i.SystemUpdate($false);
```